# Effect of subdatasheet property in Access database on the performance

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have read that if a subdatasheet property in a table is Automatic,then the performance reduces.
Would you please tell me the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This automatically assigned property is inherited by forms and
>   subforms displayed in datasheet view. Clearly, this is not a good idea
>   and may have unintended consequences in applications imported from
>   earlier versions. Worse still, there are serious performance issues
>   associated with loading a form that has several subforms where Access
>   is figuring out and collecting data from multiple more related tables.

-- http://allenbrowne.com/bug-09.html